# Unable to switch to root user from shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I want to change the user and group of /application directory for list of server.

I have created the below script, when i run the script then it prompt for the password, when i enter the password nothing is happening script is strucking there itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=hosts.txt
for HOST in $(grep -v '^#' $file)
do
ssh -T $HOST <<EOF
sudo su - root
chown root:root /application
echo "Hostname : " \$(hostname)
EOF
sleep 2
done
```

Below is the prompting output

```
[mayana@TestHOST test1]$ sh test.sh
Last login: Fri Nov  9 14:06:56 2018 from TestHOST.com
sudo su - root
[mayana@TargetHost1 ~]$ sudo su - root
[sudo] password for mayana: Password
^CKilled by signal 2.
^C
[mayana@TestHOST test1]$
```

Please help me how can i pass the password for this script.

Comment: What you actually want to do is change `/etc/sudoers` and allow the user running your script to run `sudo /path/to/script.sh` without password. This is a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), though.

Answer (score 2):

When you run this command:

```
sudo su - root
```

It starts an interactive root shell.  It does not cause the remaining commands in the script to run as root.

You need to give the specific command to run as parameters to `sudo`:

```
sudo chown root:root /application
```

The script will still prompt for a password but after that it will continue running.

Comment: If we use the above command its prompting for password but not working..Sturck at same stage.

Comment: Yes,

Please find the below Script

`mayana@TestHOST test1]$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
file=hosts.txt
for HOST in $(grep -v '^#' $file)
do
ssh -tt $HOST <<EOF
sudo chown mayana:mayana /app/mayana
EOF
sleep 2
done`